# get custom setting fields names in apex class

Tags: apex, trigger, schema, business-logic

Requirement-I need to create a map of custom setting in apex class with fields and value like.

"Name":"test",
"cal__c":"tesq",
"industry__c":"manu"

how we can get custom setting fields in apex class.is this possible using schema

Comment: What is the type of your Custom Setting? Is it a List or Hierarchy? Nevertheless you can always access the Custom Settings records and then put the values on a map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a describe call for custom settings.

If you have a custom setting named CustomSetting__c then use describe call which will return a map of all the fields :-

```
Set<String> flds = CustomSetting__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();
```

It will return a set of Field names for the custom setting